# How do you bind to a complex object in usercontrol.resources for Windows Phone 8.1 (C#)

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1

I have searched the web for the last few days but can't seem to find something that I would have thought was quite a simple task.  I would like to add a resource in my XAML page of my windows phone application which will reference a complex object but I can't find the correct method.  Is this possible?  Object is made up something similar to:

```
Public class ComplexClass
{
  Public string name { get; set; }
  Public int ID { get; set; }

  Public observablecollection<SimpleClass> simpleObjects { get; set; }

  Public addSimpleObject(SimpleClass newSimpleObject)
  {
    if (simpleObjects == null)
      simpleObjects = new ObservableCollection<SimpleClass>();

    simpleObjects.Add(newSimpleObject);
  }
}

Public Class SimpleClass
{
  Public String Name { get; set; }
  Public String Disc { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Do you want to declare an instance of `ComplexClass` in the resource dictionary of your page?

Comment: yep, in the resources so that I can then bind to ComplexClass.name in a textbox and ComplexClass.simpleObjects in a listview

Comment: I don't think you should go about it this way (via resources). Normally you'd have a ComplexClass instance exposed in your view model. Then you'd set the Page's DataContext to the view model instance, and then you can bind to properties on the DataContext. That way, the ComplexClass instance is accessible from the view and the view model. Does this make sense?

Comment: Any chance you could put some code up, I've not really coded that much with XAML which I think is part of the problem, not great at using the binding stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) do achieve this. There are already heaps of tutorials available that you can access to show you how to follow this design pattern, so I won't go into that.

Instead I'll just show you a simple way of getting the data to your view.

In the constructor of your UserControl (or Page or whatever), set up the DataContext to an instance of your ComplexClass:

```
ComplexClass complexClass;

public MyUserControl1()
{
    complexClass = new ComplexClass();
    complexClass.AddSimpleObject(new SimpleClass { Name = "Bob" });
    this.DataContext = complexClass;

    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

Then in your XAML you can bind to it like this:

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <!-- Binding to properties on ComplexClass -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SimpleObjects}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <!-- Binding to properties on SimpleClass -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Disc}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Without knowing specifics of your code, it's hard for me to suggest a method that is most suitable for you. I'd read up on MVVM and view models.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will check it once I get back from work tonight.  I forgot to say I was trying to use CollectionViewSource and setting the source property in the code behind but that was resulting in a Value out of range error, hopefully this datacontext option will work.

Comment: Typically you'd only use CollectionViewSource if you want grouping and/or to maintain the current item across multiple ListView controls. Otherwise it's unnecessary.